# Learning Basics --- Extracting Extensions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Working on an Edabit challenge and running into a situation that frequently confuses me. Still learning basics so I apologize if my terminology is off or unclear.

The challenge was to separate an array of file names with extensions from their extensions. I used toString and split methods across two lines to separate all the tests into arrays that contain the file names and extensions separately. With the first file name being position 0 and the first extension being 1.

So from here I thought using a for loop starting at position 1 and incrementing every other value (i+=2) would work. Just unsure how to return the values at this point. I can console.log the index at this point and it prints what I want to get but, if i say return index it just returns the first item, and if I create a new array and use push method it just returns a set of numbers. Unsure what to do, or if this was the right thing to do.

Code for ref this is after splitting the original tests into arrays that contained only the file names and extension names as separate items.

```
for(let i = 1; i < stringPeriod.length; i+=2){
        console.log(stringPeriod[i])
        }
```

this will print the extension names but not separated as a single array which I need to pass the challenge.

Comment: You can access the next item in the array with `i+1`, so `return [stringPeriod[i], stringPeriod[i+1]]` if you want to return an array for each, where `arr[0]` is the filename and `arr[1]` is the extension.

Comment: "I can console.log the index at this point and it prints what I want to get but, if i say return index it just returns the first item" - what do you mean?  You can see exactly the right stuff when you run your loop with the console log? you should be all set, what do you mean by "if i say return index" - how are you doing that (as any return statement within the loop will end the loop)?

Comment: ok my bad. so if i console.log the variable stringPeriod before the for loop it is `[ 'project1', 'jpg', 'project1', 'pdf', 'project1', 'mp3' ]` but after the above for loop the console log of just stringperiod is the same thing just repeated 3 times but if i console log stringPeriod[i] i get ` jpg pdf mp3 `which is what i want but  theyre not inside of an array or separated by quotes which is needed to pass the challenge  @Kyle @Matt U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  You need an array with just the extensions?

You can accomplish it with a new array (I have a feeling it wasn't working for you because you were probably just pushing "i" into the new array)

```
var newArray = [];
for(let i = 1; i < stringPeriod.length; i+=2){
    newArray.push(stringPeriod[i]);
}
console.log(newArray);
```